# How to create onclick ajax function in prestashop (1.7) and build right url link

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, module, prestashop-1.7

I created an ajax reference in javasctript and I expect the link to be realized, it has appealed to the `ajax_[modulename].php` file in the background, but the url address is ignored and the main address is inserted into the module. I do not know what is causing this. Please help.

I created the javascript code in the file .... tpl as below. Then I added the `ajax_[modulename].php` file which I placed in the main module directory

The expected effect is to display messages that confirm this part is working correctly.

Unfortunately, this is not done in the background and the reference that is returned is the main link of the module.

The site is reloaded and the link `"index.php? Controller = AdminModules & token = 3213789e146f56adaa445b96bb79956f & configure = dpeasye & module_name = dpeasy & List"` is executed.

File - **display_list.tpl**

```
<td class="text-right">
    <div class="btn-group-action pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href=".../index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=3213789e146f56adaa445b96bb79956f&configure=dpeasye&module_name=dpeasye&id_field=47&ListDic=mg">
          <i class="icon-layer"></i>
              Display Sub
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href=".../index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=3213789e146f56adaa445b96bb79956f&configure=dpeasye&module_name=dpeasye&id_field=47&UpdateDic=mg">
          <i class="icon-edit"></i>
              Edytuj
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href=".../index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=3213789e146f56adaa445b96bb79956f&configure=dpeasye&module_name=dpeasye&id_field=47&DeleteDic=mg">
          <i class="icon-trash"></i>
              Delete
        </a>
        <a id="active-47" class="btn btn-success ajax-status" href=" " title="Enabled">
            <i class="icon-check"></i>
             Enabled
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
<td class="text-right">
    <div class="btn-group-action pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href=".../index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=3213789e146f56adaa445b96bb79956f&configure=dpeasye&module_name=dpeasye&id_field=65&ListDic=tt">
          <i class="icon-layer"></i>
              Display Sub
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href=".../index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=3213789e146f56adaa445b96bb79956f&configure=dpeasye&module_name=dpeasye&id_field=65&UpdateDic=tt">
          <i class="icon-edit"></i>
              Edytuj
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href=".../index.php?controller=AdminModules&token=3213789e146f56adaa445b96bb79956f&configure=dpeasye&module_name=dpeasye&id_field=65&DeleteDic=tt">
          <i class="icon-trash"></i>
              Delete
        </a>
        <a id="active-65" class="btn btn-success ajax-status" href=" " title="Enabled">
            <i class="icon-check"></i>
            Enabled
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

File - **display_list.tpl**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('a.ajax-status').click(function() {
    var MainUrl = "";
    var abtn = $(this);
    var aidall = $(this).attr('id');
    var aid = $(this).attr('id').replace('active-', '');
    var aclass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    var atitle = $(this).attr('title');
    var atext = $(this).text();
        atext = atext.replace('\n', '');
    var iclass = $(this).children().attr('class');
    var data = '&id_field=' + aid ;

     $.ajax({
        url: baseDir + 'modules/dpeasye/ajax_dpeasye.php?action=changeStatus',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(aid){

            if (aclass.class[2] == 'btn-danger'){
                abtn.fadeOut(700);
                atext.replace('Enabled','Disabled');
                aclass[2].replace('btn-success','btn-danger');
                atitle.replace('Enabled','Disabled');
                iclass.replace('icon-check','icon-remove');
                abtn.fadeIn(700);
            }
            if (aclass.class[2] == 'btn-danger'){
                abtn.fadeOut(700);
                atext.replace('Disabled','Enabled');
                aclass[2].replace('btn-danger','btn-success');
                atitle.replace('Disabled','Enabled');
                iclass.replace('icon-remove','icon-check');
                abtn.fadeIn(700);
            }
        showSuccessMessage(update_success_msg);
        },
        failure:function(aid){
            console.log('test ok');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

File - **ajax_dpeasye.php**

```php
include_once('../../config/config.inc.php');
include_once('../../init.php');
include_once('dpeasye.php');

if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    switch ($_GET['action']) {
        case 'changeStatus':
            $this->displayConfirmation($this->trans('Test passed'));       
        break;
        case 'sort':
        break;
    }
} else {
    die('no action passed');
}
```

Why does the main link appear if there is no link in the link: `"<a id="active-65" class="btn btn-success ajax-status" href="" title="Enabled"> <i class = "icon -check "> </ i> Enabled </a>"`?

What is the reason that the javascript code is not being executed?

Comment: Is there some valid reason for using `<a>` instead of `<button>`?

Comment: No, it is no one reason. It is posible to use <button> insead of <a>.